# SQL Server 2014 Express - Update trigger not executing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2014-express

I installed SQL Server 2014 Express to test it a little (never used it before) and run into some difficulties,mainly with triggers.

First, I don't know why "new Trigger" under the tab `Triggers` (of the selected table) is grayed out.

Maybe because I have not used the table yet...don't know....

Well, I tried to do it with a query:

```
create trigger dbo.after_update 
on dbo.MyTable
for UPDATE
as begin
   if not update(edited)
      update dbo.Mytable 
      set edited = GETDATE()
      where TW_ID IN (SELECT TW_ID FROM inserted)
END
GO
```

I get the error :

> Msg 8197, Level 16, State 4, Procedure after_update, Line 1
>   The object 'MyTable' does not exist or is invalid for this operation.

`TW_ID` is an `identity` column. Edited is `smalldatetime`.

There are no joined tables. All I want is to update the column `edited` when someone updates the table.

Comment: Do you have a case sensitive collation? Does that table actually exist? The code you posted does not have the same case for the object name and the table in your update statement.

Comment: table exists,of course... for the rest, I dont know....like I said,never used this before....:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.after_update 
ON dbo.MyTable
FOR UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE t 
      SET t.edited = GETDATE()
    FROM dbo.Mytable t 
    INNER JOIN inserted I  ON t.TW_ID = I.TW_ID
END
GO
```

Comment: there are no joined tables. all I want is to update the field "edited" when someone updates the table.

Comment: exactly you would only update the rows which were updated therefore you need to join your table with inserted table which will filter out only the rows that were updated by the update statement and update their edited field with current datetime.

Comment: why is this trigger firing after an insert also ?

Comment: Why do you think it is firing after an INSERT? Perhaps there is a DEFAULT CONSTRAINT on the edited column.